# Receiving null Value while using POST method in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I want to send a string by using POST method in servlet so that it can communicate with other servlet application present in other domain. But I am receiving null in my Input steam object.

My Code:

```
    String content = "10 141 nahush123 01";
    URL url = new URL("http://52.220.37.12:8080/servers/servers");
    System.out.println(url.toString());
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    httpCon.setDoInput(true);
    httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
    httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");

    OutputStream os = httpCon.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
    out.write(content);
    //br = BufferReader(out);
    System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());
    writer.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());


    httpCon.connect();
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream()));
    //reading response 
    //String resp;
    //if(br != null){
        content = br.readLine();
    //}
    System.out.println(content);
    writer.println(content);
    out.flush();
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    out.close();
    os.close();
```

Comment: Why do you write to the outputstream before connecting ?

Comment: Trying to pass string as a parameter.

Comment: I tried to connect before outputsteam still it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy pasted your code in my servlet worked fine

1. Check that you overrided doPost method in the servlet
2. Check that you that your post metod work fine and return value, I use ["DHC Rest Client"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-rest-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) plugin for chrome. It is very cool tool
3. Try to remove httpCon.connect() line. It is not necessary.

   From oracle docs about connect() method:

> Operations that depend on being connected, like getContentLength, will
> implicitly perform the connection, if necessary.

Operations getResponseMessage, getResponseCode perform the connection.

UPDATED

I tried to test with my local test url and it works. Then i tried with your url and it does not work.

You need to flush output stream before use input stream.

This code work and return "0#5#26#Temperature#Living_Room#555555581#0+0#7#0#Room1#Master_bedroom#555555581#1+1#7#0#Door1#Living_Room#555555581#2+1#6#0#frontdoor#Living_Room#555555581#2+0#6#0#doorback#Balcony#555555581#2+"

```
PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter();
String content = "10 141 nahush123 01";
URL url = new URL("http://52.220.37.12:8080/servers/servers");
System.out.println(url.toString());
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoInput(true);
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");

OutputStream os = httpCon.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
out.write(content);
out.flush();
//br = BufferReader(out);
System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseCode());
System.out.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());
writer.println(httpCon.getResponseMessage());


//httpCon.connect();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream()));
//reading response
//String resp;
//if(br != null){
content = br.readLine();
//}
System.out.println(content);
writer.println(content);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
out.close();
os.close();
```

Comment: Can you share what response you received? I am looking for string as a response text and it won't contain OK. 

Response text must be
0#7#0#Room1#Master_bedroom#555555581#1+1#7#0#Door1#Living_Room#555555581#2+0#5#26#Temperature#Living_Room#555555581#0+1#6#0#frontdoor#Living_Room#555555581#2+0#6#0#doorback#Balcony#555555581#2+

Comment: @NahushSarje I updated my answer. Can't paste code here

Answer (score 0):

Try with getparameter() function in the servlet

Comment: I am trying to send that string mentioned in the content variable. And in return I will get a string only. So I don't think getparameter() will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method with your pass string parameter:

```
public String postData(String reqStr) {
ObjectOutputStream objOS = null;
ObjectInputStream objIS = null;
HttpURLConnection servletCon = null;
try {
if (reqStr != null) {
Thread.sleep(1000);
objOS.writeObject(reqStr);
} else {
throw new Exception("request is null.");
}
} catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Failed to send request to server.", ex);
    }
    String response = null;
    try {
        objIS = new ObjectInputStream(servletCon.getInputStream());
        response = (String) objIS.readObject();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Failed to get response from server.", ex);
        response = null;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Initializing Connection like you but calling differently:

```
public void initializeUrlConnection(String servletURL, String contentType, String method) {

    try {

        logger.debug("Servlet URL " + servletURL);
        url = new URL(servletURL);
        servletCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        servletCon.setUseCaches(false);
        servletCon.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
        servletCon.setDoInput(true);
        servletCon.setDoOutput(true);
        servletCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
        servletCon.setRequestMethod(method);
        objOS = new ObjectOutputStream(servletCon.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        logger.error("Failed to initialize Http Connection.", ex);
    }
}
```

First of call initialize connection method with required parameter:

```
Object.initializeUrlConnection(url, contentType,method);
```

then call posDataMethod with your string/json parameter:

```
Object.postData(str);
```

Comment: HI Vimal, where is the url?

Comment: I hope now u understand more.