# Invalid CORS request seen only in UCBrowser

Tags: spring-mvc, security, tomcat, cors, progressive-web-apps

When redirecting from `abc.mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com`, I get **"Invalid CORS request"** in **UCBrowser**, but it works perfectly fine in other browsers like Chrome, Firefox etc. HTTP status code in response is 403.

I'm redirecting by `response.sendRedirect("www.mydomain.com");`

`abc.mydomain.com` points to a Java+spring-mvc app deployed on Tomcat 8 and `www.mydomain.com` points to a Progressive Web App (using Spring as container) on the same tomcat instance.

Why does UC browser behave differently as compared to Chrome?

There was no such peculiarity mentioned on caniuse.com. I didn't find any relevant information on this by Googling or searching on SO either.

Answer (score 0):

Best information I had about CORS ever...

[Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://........](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663164/cross-origin-request-blocked-the-same-origin-policy-disallows-reading-the-remot/38663606#38663606)

Refer:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Here something about Java: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Thanks, but I have been through these already. I can't find any information on why it would work on Chrome and not on UC Browser.